# Problem with multiline string in userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am having a issue with multiline stings in a userform.

When a user selects a option, the code checks if the selected answer matches the correct answer and then shows if right or wrong. But in either case the code says it is wrong.

Example of a option is:

If you see the string, brush it off sideways

Place icepack/cold flannel to reduce swelling

Elevate area to reduce bloodflow

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
rowNum = Selection.Row - Selection.ListObject.Range.Row

DeclareVars

Column = examtable.ListColumns("Right ans").DataBodyRange(rowNum)
    
CorrectAns = examtable.ListColumns("Right ans").DataBodyRange(rowNum).Offset(0, Column)
RightWrong.Visible = True
    
    If OptionButton1.Caption = CorrectAns Then
        RightWrong.BackColor = &HFF00&
        RightWrong.Caption = "Right"
    Else
        RightWrong.BackColor = &HFF&
        RightWrong.Caption = "Wrong"
    End If


End Sub
```

What i am expecting is that if correct, shows right, or wrong if incorrect

Comment: What is in the string `CorrectAns` and what is in `OptionButton1.Caption`? Debug, compare the two and you will see why it is always false.

Comment: In this case, both the `CorrectAns` and `OptionButton1.Caption` are the same

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have multiple option buttons below one another? Option button one will always have the same caption. If it is selected it can become true (indicated by the black dot), but the caption will not change.

Lets say it looks like this
[two option buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhmI4.png)

Then the upper is called OptionButton1, the lower OptionButton2.

You can check

```
If OptionButton1 then
   RightWrong.BackColor = &HFF00&
   RightWrong.Caption = "Right"
Else
   RightWrong.BackColor = &HFF&
   RightWrong.Caption = "Wrong"
End if
```

You could use a combobox (these are the drop down menus).

You could populate it with an array of the strings you want to test and ask if the answers concur.

When loading the user form use

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
 
    ComboBox1.list = Array("brush it off sideways", "Place icepack/cold flannel to reduce swelling", "Elevate area to reduce bloodflow")

End Sub
```

this will look as followed

[The user form with the list open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5alD.png)

Then you can say `combobox.value = CorrectAns`